# How do I use CSV Writers with GZIP files in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to port some code from Python 2.7 to Python 3. The 2to3 tool works fine for the base syntax and package changes, but now we're into some strange side effects.

I have the following code block. It opens a temporary file name using the gzip module.

```
f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
f.close()
fn = f.name + '.gz'
os.rename(f.name, fn)
fz = gzip.open(fn, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(fz, delimiter='\t', lineterminator=lt)
for row in table:
    writer.writerow(row)
fz.close()
```

The problem is that executing this gives me the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 343, in write
self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I've tried opening the gzip file as 'w' instead of 'wb', but to no avail. I'm guessing the gzip module is expecting a byte array, but the CSV Writer doesn't or won't provide anything other than a string.

How do people do this in Python 3?

*Edit:* I should mention that this code block executes without issue in Python 2.7.

Comment: You should try it in write mode. fz = gzip.open(fn, 'w', newline='')

Comment: Nope, I get the same `ValueError` as above. I'm looking into having to refactor it as a GzipFile wrapped in an TextIOWrapper per the docs. They're not very detailed on that front.

Comment: change the mode to `wt` , not `wb` .

Comment: I add the comment as an answer ! ;)

Comment: Also you can use `writer.writerows(table)`, without iterating other `table` by yourself

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to change the mode of `gzip` to `wt` :

```
fz = gzip.open(fn, 'wt')
```

Also a little-known feature of `gzip.open()` and `bz2.open()` is that they can be layered
on top of an existing file opened in binary mode. For example, this works:

```
import gzip
f = open('somefile.gz', 'rb')
with gzip.open(f, 'rt') as g:
    text = g.read()
```

This allows the gzip and bz2 modules to work with various file-like objects such as
sockets, pipes, and in-memory files.

Comment: Yup, Python 3 means you have to be very VERY careful with the flags used to open the files. Man, what a headache.

Comment: @WineSoaked :) , yes ,and also a little-known feature of `gzip.open()` and `bz2.open()` is that they can be layered
on top of an existing file opened in binary mode .

Comment: You should open for writing with `gzip.open(fn, 'wt', newline='')`, otherwise csv's newline handling may be compromised (ie: if a csv entry has an embedded newline).

Comment: If in the same script you want to upload that file, then you need to close the file handler `f`, otherwise the uploaded gzip file will be damaged. So just do `f.close()` after the `with` block.